# How to print only odd-numbered solutions with ExSheets?

Tags: numbering, exsheets

I want to have a section at the end of each chapter with the solutions of only odd-numbered questions.

Comment: It seems to me the O.P. raised a quite sensible question.

Comment: Done. I had missed that answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want `\printsolution[section]` to only print the solutions of odd numbered questions you can add

```
\usepackage{exsheets}[2016/01/26]% make sure you have v0.21 available

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__exsheets_print_solutions_section:nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \exsheets_print_solutions_if:nnn
      {
        \int_if_odd_p:n  { \l_exsheets_counter_qu_int } &&
        \int_compare_p:n { \l__exsheets_counter_sec_int = #3 }
      }
      {#1}
      {#2}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

to you document. Since this redefines an internal function this is not entirely safe, though.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{exsheets}[2016/01/26]

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__exsheets_print_solutions_section:nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \exsheets_print_solutions_if:nnn
      {
        \int_if_odd_p:n  { \l_exsheets_counter_qu_int } &&
        \int_compare_p:n { \l__exsheets_counter_sec_int = #3 }
      }
      {#1}
      {#2}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{One}
\subsection{Exercises}
\begin{question}
  qu one
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  sol one
\end{solution}

\begin{question}
  qu two
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  sol two
\end{solution}

\begin{question}
  qu three
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  sol three
\end{solution}

\begin{question}
  qu four
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  sol four
\end{solution}

\begin{question}
  qu five
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  sol five
\end{solution}

\subsection{Solutions}
\printsolutions[section]

\newpage

\section{Two}
\subsection{Exercises}
\begin{question}
  qu one
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  sol one
\end{solution}

\begin{question}
  qu two
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  sol two
\end{solution}

\begin{question}
  qu three
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  sol three
\end{solution}

\begin{question}
  qu four
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  sol four
\end{solution}

\begin{question}
  qu five
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  sol five
\end{solution}

\subsection{Solutions}
\printsolutions[section]

\end{document}
```

[image]